# git add -A does not adding all files of project to git repository

Tags: git, git-push, git-add

I have just created new repository on github and trying to add my project on git.

When my friend tried to clone using `git clone` this project, some files of my project were not cloned.

On inspecting more on this, I found that these files were not added from my side to git. Steps followed by me to add whole project to git:

```
git add -A
git commit -am "First Commit"
git push origin master
```

But, still some files were not added to git. I tried by changing permissions of these files from **read-only** to **rwx** and adding again. But, nothing changed.

Comment: Do you have `.gitignore`?

Comment: yes, I have `.gitignore` file @ArkadiuszDrabczyk

Comment: If I use `git add -f -A` then `.gitignore` is ignored and all files are added to git repository.

Comment: Then how can I pull these files added by ignoring `.gitignore` to my friend's pc ?

Comment: `.gitignore` is only used for add/commit. Your friend does not need to worry about `.gitignore` if they are pulling files you have already added to the repository.

Comment: Yes, you was right `.gitignore` does not affecting pull operation @DanLowe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My project was having `.gitignore` file containing list of files and folders that were ignored during git add. So, I again added my project using

```
git add -f -A
git commit -am "Add Project"
git push origin master
```

Where

-f : adding files forcefully, ignoring .gitignore

-A : adding whole project

I have not removed anything from `.gitignore` because I want them to be added only once, not all the time when adding project to git.